# How to detect if current page in Firefox is rendered in "No Style" view?

Tags: javascript, firefox

Firefox supports a "No Style" view mode which strips off all the CSS styling in a web page. Is there any way to detect if current page is rendered using "No Style" mode ? Preferably in JavaScript

Comment: you can simply check if a style you declared on en element is present.

Comment: For what it's worth, "No Style" will pretty much ruin the layout of any modern web site. Most people using this feature will be familiar with what it does, and won't fault you for it. (For instance, Google, Amazon, and Yahoo all look like total garbage with it turned on.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  But you might be able to dream something up by setting an element's style to some known value, then using JavaScript to check that value after the page has loaded.  If it's not what you expected, you *might* be in the scenario you mention.

```
<div id="no-style"></div>
```

...CSS:

```
#no-style { z-index:100; }
```

Then check the z-index value on page load.  Does it equal 100?

Cheers